# python simple server with 3.4.2

Tags: angularjs, python-3.4, simplehttpserver

I'm not savvy with Python or server programming at all. My AVG blocked Python from running SimpleHTTPServer. I was able to install Python 3.4.2 successfully, but noticed that SimpleHTTPServer has been moved into HTTP server.

How can I set up my machine or Python 3.4.2 so that I can just type python -m SimpleHTTPServer when working on my AngularJS projects locally?

I'm running Windows 7 64.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved it by re-installing python on my machine.